# 500 internal error after first request node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to save data in MongoDB with the help of async library. When I try to do it, the server works fine for the first request and  after that start throwing a 500: Internal Server Error on every request. There is no log on the console for this. 
Can someone please help me out with this problem?

**routes.js**

```
var listingsHandler = require('../custom/listings-handler');
listingsController.post('/addNew', isLoggedIn, function(req, res, next){
  listingsHandler.createNewListing(req, res);
});
```

**../custom/listings-handler.js**

```
"createNewListing": function(req, res){

var deserializedRequestData = jsonHandler.deserializer(req.body, 'data');

deserializedRequestData["_id"] = deserializedRequestData.aliasNameOfListing;
var primaryCategoryOfListing = deserializedRequestData.primaryCategory;
deserializedRequestData["listingNumber"] = 1000000;
async.waterfall([
  function(callback){
    //The code below calls a module that generate a Mongoose model for me
    //which will be used to save the data in the next function.

    var Listings = modelEngine.modelGenerators.listings(primaryCategoryOfListing);
    callback(null, Listings);
  },

  function(Listings, callback){
    //This function creates a new object from the model named Listings and then 
    //saves it.
    var currentListing = new Listings(deserializedRequestData);
    currentListing.save(callback);
  }
],
 function(err, resp){
  if(err){
    if(err.code == 11000){
      res.send("duplicate");
    }else{
      res.send("ERRR");
    }
  }else{
    res.send(JSON.stringify(resp));
  }
});
```

The above code only works fine for the first request and throws a 500: Internal Server Error on all consequent requests. Nothing is shown on the Node.JS console so I am unable to discern where the problem lies. The request is the same every single time and therefore ideally it should work as many times as it's called.

**Edit 1:**

The code for modelGenerator.listings() is as follows

```
    var schemaObject = jsonEngine.categoryDetails.listingsSchema[category];
    schemaObject = this.addBasicDetails(schemaObject);
    var listingSchema = new mongoose.Schema(schemaObject);
    var Listings = mongoose.model("Listings", listingSchema);
    return Listings;
```

**Note:** jsonEngine.categoryDetails.listingsSchema is the function that generates a different schema for each category. addBasic details is the function that adds more fields.

Comment: The error is not shown  because it is occuring within the `.waterfall` call and not at a point where an "async" function passes the error. A try/catch would expose the error when passed to `callback(err)` on the catch. But there is also no need for the `waterfall` here at all as the model recall is not an async method. Given the naming "modelGenerators", I would suspect that code to be at fault, and also likely not needed.

Comment: The type listing has different schema for different **primaryCategoryOfListing** that is why I cannot get rid of the **modelGenerators**. Is it a wrong way to code? Could you please suggest some documentation from where I can study how to write an elegant alternative to this? @BlakesSeven

Comment: @BlakesSeven Thank you. I tried using try catch for the statements and it turned out to be a model overwrite error.

Comment: Which is what I said initially. Neither the `waterfall` is required here, nor your logic about "generating models". Models in mongoose are **one time register**, and you should not need to do otherwise. So it was always clear that your implentation "outside" the presented code was at fault.You should start asking questions about how to use mongoose models, since you clearly do not fully understand the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @BlakesSeven, I was able to figure out the problem. Every time a new request is received at the server, it tries to recompile the **Listings** model again. Since models in Mongoose are meant to be compiled once and then used globally across all requests, this error was happening.

Using a try catch on each and every individual function helped a lot.